# Gracefully shutdown Spring application running in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes

I've implemented graceful shutdown logic in my Spring application and it works locally if I send a SIGTERM to the Java process.

However when I'm running it in Kubernetes if I delete the pod or deploy a new one, the logic is not running. First I thought that it's sending SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM but as I've researched, the Docker CMD gets the SIGTERM but does not delegate it to the application. How should I run it correctly?

Right now I'm using this command in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
```

Comment: Use [preStop](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/), and checkout why [SIGTERM note delegated to app](https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html)

Comment: @Oleg Butuzov could you expand your comment and post it as an answer?

Comment: @OlegButuzov thank you, I've found the article about SIGTERM not delegated, but unfortunately I couldn't make it work. Can you explain how to edit the Dockerfile? I'm using Alpine base image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#dumb-init) or something similar. The README at the given link elaborates a bit on "Why you need an init system".

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed I think!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of container handlers for graceful shutdown. k8s supports post-start and pre-stop hooks as container handlers. call your logic in prestop hook

Comment: I'd rather not use the hooks and rely on the SIGTERM signal. How can I edit my Dockerfile so it gets delegated?